# Powershell script to create a snapshot and store it into a storage account in another location

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Using powershell script, I need to create a snapshot of a VM and save the snapshot in a storage account which is in a different region. The snapshot name should also contain the date on which it was taken, so that it can be auto deleted after 30 days. Do let me know how to achieve this.
Also another major issue I am facing is how to store the snapshot in the storage account without using keys directly in the script.

This is the old script which I am using, it does not has the date in the snapshot name feature and uses storage account keys directly in the script, which is not secure.

```
 #powershell script to create a snapshot

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'subs name'

$subscriptionId = 'xxxxxx'

$resourceGroupName = "Rgname"

$vmName="VMname"

$Location = "East US"

#how to get-date in the name of the snap
$snapshotName = "snapname"


$vmOSDisk=(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName).StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name

$Disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $vmOSDisk

$SnapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $Disk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $Location

$Snapshot=New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshotConfig -SnapshotName `
      $snapshotName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName






#powershell script to convert snapshot into managed disks
      
$diskName = 'ManagedDiskname'

#Provide the size of the disks in GB. It should be greater than the VHD file size.
$diskSize = '128'


$storageType = 'Premium_LRS'

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName 

$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -SkuName $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id

New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName






#powershell script to save managed disk into a storage account which is in a different location

$sasExpiryDuration = "3600"

$storageAccountName = "storageacctname"

$storageContainerName = "containername"

$storageAccountKey = '(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "Snapshot-Powershell" -AccountName "storageforsnap")'

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy the VHD of the managed disk. 
$storageAccountKey = 'xxxxxx'


$destinationVHDFileName = "vhdfilename"

. 
$useAzCopy = 1 


Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId


$sas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName -DurationInSecond $sasExpiryDuration -Access Read 


$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

#Copy the VHD of the managed disk to the storage account
if($useAzCopy -eq 1)
{
    $containerSASURI = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Context $destinationContext -ExpiryTime(get-date).AddSeconds($sasExpiryDuration) -FullUri -Name $storageContainerName -Permission rw
    azcopy copy $sas.AccessSAS $containerSASURI

}else{

    Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName
}
```

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: Is that you want to implement auto-deleted with the snapshot?

Comment: Yes that is one of the tasks. But the main issue I have is saving the snapshot in a storage account, when both storage account and snapshot are in different regions. Since I don't want to use the storage account key directly into my powershell script as that would create a security concern. So, any other method to achieve the same along with how to implement them through powershell would be great, like using azure key vault, etc

Comment: Using powershell, how to store storage account keys in azure key vault and then retrieve those keys and use them to authenticate and store the snapshot/disk in that storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. Azure snapshot can be auto deleted after 30 days**

As far as I knew, Azure does not provide the feature. But we can implement it via a schedule task.

For example

1. [Enable Run As account in Azure automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account#create-a-run-as-account-in-azure-portal)
2. Install module `Az.Automation` `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Compute` in the automation account. Regarding how to install, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-modules-from-the-powershell-gallery)
3. Create Azure Powershell runbook with the following script in the automation ccount. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-powershell).

```
#get the snpshots created before 30 days
Get-AzSnapshot| Where-Object{($_.TimeCreated -lt ([datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-30)))}
foreach($snp in $snps){
  $snp| Remove-AzSnapshot -Force
}
```

4. [Create a schedule for the Azure runbook.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules)

> **2. How to securely connect Azure blob**

If you want to securely connect Azure blob, we can implement it with Azure AD auth. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).

For example

1. Assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to user or sp

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName <email> `
    -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Contributor" `
    -Scope  "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/sample-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"
```

2. Script

```
Connect-AzAccount
$ResourceGroupName=""
$snapshotName=""
$sasExpiryDuration=3600

$sas =Grant-AzSnapshotAccess  -SnapshotName $snapshotName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -DurationInSecond $sasExpiryDuration -Access Read 

$storageAccountName=""
$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount

$storageContainerName="image"
$destinationVHDFileName="test.vhd"
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName

#check copy state
Get-AzStorageBlobCopyState -Container $storageContainerName -Blob $destinationVHDFileName -Context $destinationContext
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting authentication issue while implementing this script, even though I have owner access to the subscription. I have pasted the error message, how to resolve it?

Comment: Start-AzStorageBlobCopy: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this o
peration using this permission.
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
ErrorMessage: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

Comment: I think I am not able to explain properly. I have a VM and a storage account both of them are in different regions.Using powershell script, I created a snapshot of the VM and using this snapshot I created a managed disk. Now I want to store this managed disk into a container in the storage account but without giving the storage account keys in the script directly. Some other way to retrieve the key indirectly or through azure key vault maybe (if possible).

Comment: @atindra please assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the account you use to login.

Comment: I have already done that, still facing the same error.

Comment: @atindra Which level do you assign?

Comment: @atindra Could you please provide the script you run?

Comment: The same which you have given here with a minor change, since i need to use it to export the disk. Wait, I'll post it here. And for the assignment. I email id which I use to login on the portal has Owner access for the subscription and I went to the IAM settings of the storage account and added the same email id as Storage Blob Data Contributor role also.l

Comment: @atindra According to my test, it is ok for me. Could you please add `-debug`  at the nad of `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` to get the detailed message?

Comment: It worked after adding -debug at the end, idk why?

Comment: While running it through a automation account, AzStorageBlobCopy is not able to perform copy action even though the service principle of the automation account has Storage Blob Data Contributor access. How else can I grant the required permissions to the automation account?

Comment: @atindra Could you please provide your script used to copy?

Comment: @atindra if you want to run the command `Get-AzStorageAccountKey` to get account key, you should be a `contributor` at the account level.

Comment: I was able to run it. I have owner privileges on the subscription, the error was due to networking of the storage account. I changed the settings to allow all networks and it worked fine.