# Unable to run my ps script through automation account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a powershell script which I want to run through azure automation account. The script worked fine when running on cloudshell but when running it through a powershell runbook it is not doing the intended tasks and throwing errors.When I am using Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'xxx' it tells me to use Connect-AzAccount and when I use that it gives me Cannot find an open port error.
Can anyone help with this? I am listing down the four different error messages I am getting.

```
Connect-AzAccount : Cannot find an open port. At line:6 char:1 + Connect-AzAccount + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand



Get-AzVM : Argument passed in is not serializable. Parameter name: value At line:19 char:12 + $vmOSDisk=(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmNa ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzVM], ArgumentException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMCommand



New-AzStorageContext : Context cannot be null. Please log in using Connect-AzAccount. At line:50 char:23 + ... onContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $destinationstor ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [New-AzStorageContext], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageContext



Start-AzStorageBlobCopy : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AbsoluteUri' because it is null. At line:55 char:38 + Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $d ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Start-AzStorageBlobCopy], ParameterBindingValidationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blo [![enter image description here][1]][1]b.Cmdlet.StartAzureStorageBlobCopy
```

Here is a snip of a part of code for reference. Az module is used in the script and new Azure automation account does not have Az module installed by default, even after importing Az.Accounts, Az.Automation, Az.Compute I am getting these errors.

Comment: What params are you sending through Connect-AzAccount? MFA enabled for the account you are using for sigh-in?

Comment: For the love of humanity, please post your _code as plain text_, not screenshots - and preferably the _actual_ code that generated the listed errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213778/powershell-script-to-create-a-snapshot-and-store-it-into-a-storage-account-in-an

Comment: The script voted as the answer is the code I am using. It worked fine on cloud shell, but not working on Azure automation account runbook.

Comment: @OlehTarasenko I am not passing any parameter with Connect-AzAccount and NO MFA is not enabled on the account I sign in with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cloud shell, it will login your user account automatically, actually `Connect-AzAccount` does not work, but it will not give you an error, just a warning, so the script will work.

In the automation runbook, it does not support the interactive way to login your user account, if you use `Connect-AzAccount` directly, you will get the error, the other errors are follow-up issues based on this.

So to solve the issues, we always use the [Run As Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/create-run-as-account) of your automation account in this scenario, essentially it is an AD App along with a service principal in your AAD tenant. Make sure you have enabled it and give all the permissions to it the same as your user account to run the script, its name is like `automationname_xxxxxxxxx`, you can check it in the `Run As Account` blade in the automation account in the portal.

Then use the commands below to login.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

After login, please use `Set-AzContext -Subscription <subscription-id>` instead of `Select-AzSubscription`, also please import `Az.Storage` module in the automation account, because some commands like `New-AzStorageContext` and `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` belong to this module, after doing them, your script should work.

**Update:**

I test with the script you used with `Storage Blob Data Contributor`, it works fine.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$sas = Grant-AzSnapshotAccess -SnapshotName "joyvmsnap" -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx"  -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read 

$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "joystoragev2" -UseConnectedAccount

$storageContainerName="image"
$destinationVHDFileName="test.vhd"
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName -Force
```

[image]

Make sure the firewall of the storage account is set to allow access from all networks and the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role is assigned at the storage account level or higher, not the container level.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, this method worked, there was some typo error at my end. Thanks.

Comment: Everything is running fine. just getting one error now. This request is not authorized to perform this operation, even though I have contributor and Storage Data Blob contributor role and same with the user account to run the script, it also has both these roles.

Comment: _**This is the error:**_ Start-AzStorageBlobCopy : This request is not authorized to perform this operation. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure ErrorMessage: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

Comment: @atindra For the new issue, I recommend you to ask it in a new post, including more details, stackoverflow avoid asking several questions in one post and it will be clear to others.

Comment: It is not a new issue, it is just that AzStorageBlobCopy is not able to perform copy action even though the service principle of the automation account has Storage Blob Data Contributor access. How else can I grant the required permissions to the automation account?

Comment: @atindra Actually it is, the new error is different from the original error, and as I know `Storage Blob Data Contributor` is enough to perform the action, did you set it for the  src storage account and dest account? I think you need to post a new question with the specific command you used, including the parameters, and did you set the firewall? Then we can do an accurate test for you.

Comment: @atindra Did a test for you, it should work, see the details in my update, make sure the firewall of the storage account is set to allow access from all networks and the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role is assigned at the storage account level or higher, not the container level.

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang , networking was the issue in my case.